# Check if a letter in a string is in a list (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

If an input has a letter that isn't in the allowed letters list then i want the program to reply saying that the letter isn't allowed.

say if I typed: abcde, then I want the program to say: The letter(s) "d,e" is not in the allowed characters list

code:

```
allowed_characters = ["a", "b", "c"]

eee = input("Enter text here: ")

if eee #has any letters that arent in allowed_characters:
  print(f"The letter(s) \"{not allowed letter}\" is not in the allowed characters list")
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
allowed_characters = ["a", "b", "c"]

input_text = input("Enter text here: ")

used_not_allowed = set(input_text) - set(allowed_characters)
if used_not_allowed:
    print(f"The letter(s) \"{used_not_allowed }\" is not in the allowed characters list")
```

Answer (score 0):

I say you use list comprehension to detect weather a letter is allowed or not.

```
allowed_characters = ["a", "b", "c"]
eee = input("Enter text here: ")
bad = [letters for letters in eee if letters not in allowed_characters]
if bad:
    print('fThese letters ({bad}) are not allowed')
```

Comment: You could simple say `if bad:`, since this checks if list is empty or not